# find all k-length subsets of list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, subset

i need to find a k-length subset of list in prolog,
i have this function:

```
    subset([], []).
    subset([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):-
    subset(Tail, NTail).
    subset([_|Tail], NTail):-
    subset(Tail, NTail).
```

and i apply another rule for the length of the list,

```
    length(Xs,Size)
```

the problem is it is very slow because it search for all-length subset,
is there a direct recursive definition for this k-length subset?

i searched for it for a week and cant find anything

Comment: What a I meant (sorry if it looked smartassing) is that you should try yourself, show what you have done and what is not working for you...

Comment: i tried this, but its not working correctly,subset_of(K, 0, [],[]).
subset_of(K, Len, [X|Xs],Zs):-
        L1 is Len - 1,
        subset_of(K, L1, Xs, Zs),
        L1 == K.
subset_of(K, Len, [X|Xs],Zs):-
        L1 is Len - 1,
        subset_of(K, L1, Xs,Ys),
        do_add(X, Ys, Zs),
        Len == K.
subsets_of(K,Xs,Xss):-
        length(Xs, Len),
        findall(Ys,subset_of(K, Len, Xs,Ys),Xss).

Comment: the idea of keeping record of the count is right, but no need to use findall. See answer for a simple modification to your original subset procedure

Comment: Great question m8! very relevant to current programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your initial solution to `subset/2`, you might add another argument (Len) and:

- Base case holds when Len = 0
- Recursive step which adds element decrements Len and finishes recursion if new Len=0

That would look:

```
 subset(0, [], []).
 subset(Len, [E|Tail], [E|NTail]):-
   succ(PLen, Len),
   (PLen > 0 -> subset(PLen, Tail, NTail) ; NTail=[]).
 subset(Len, [_|Tail], NTail):-
   subset(Len, Tail, NTail).
```

Comment: You might change the first clause to `subset(0, _, []):- !.` as when Len is zero the result must be the empty list regardless of the input list... Not sure if it will really improve performance noticeably.