# Prolog : Determine all sub-sets of collinear points

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I am having some trouble with the following assignment:

> There are given N points in a plane (through their coordinates).
>   Determine all sub-sets of collinear points using Backtracking in
>   Prolog.

I don't know how to check if 3 or more points are collinear in Prolog or how to use the backtracking.

Comment: Checking if it's collinear isn't program language specific. It's just playing with the syntax. Prolog is all about backtracking, have you done any prolog before you can relate to?

Comment: 3 or more points are co-linear if the slopes of the lines through one selected point to any one of the other points are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a solution but I'm going to avoid sharing it completely unless you ask for it specifically. Instead I'll sort of outline the shape of the solution and see if that is enough for you to fill in the details.

My solution is simple. I select a point from the input and compute its slope. Then, I walk through the rest of the input collecting other points whose slope matches. So for starters, you at least need a predicate `slope/2` which computes the slope of a point. You can use `select/3` to choose an item from a list and give you the rest of the list; this is a very convenient driver for this kind of problem because the backtracking behavior of `select/3` will do exactly what you want: it will get the next point from the list as well as give you the list without that point in it.

This approach will work and I recommend you try it because it is simple. It will produce the same information multiple times though. You can fix that by changing your loop driver a bit, make it so that it removes points that have already been used from further consideration. I did that with an "or" and a recursive call.

Also, for fun, I defined an operator `@` so that I could discuss points as `X@Y` or `3@4` but this is not necessary for the solution, it's just pretty.

**Edit:** to answer directly your question of how to check 3 or more points, you have a list of points and you check each one individually. If it passes, you keep it; otherwise you discard it.

Comment: If you want unique sets, your select approach may cause that [1,2,3], will lead to triples (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836327/find-all-k-length-subsets-of-list-in-prolog

Comment: True, and I mentioned that, but the reference is appreciated. :)